# Perl array has values but unable to access them

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I have tried, I have searched in the internet and I am out of ideas at this moment.
I have an array which has elements.
I use to Dumper function to ensure that the elements are present however, when I try to access individual items, I don't get the expected output.

And someone please help.

This is the code

```
print "<pre>Array: ".Dumper(@configFiles)."\n";
print "First: ".$configFiles[0]."\n";
print "Second: ".$configFiles[1]."</pre>";
```

Below is the output

```
Array: $VAR1 = [
      'searchTables.json',
      'NAM_database.json'
    ];

First: ARRAY(0x9a8f60)
Second:
```

In case you are wondering how were the array elements assigned, I read a json file then converted it with the function below.

```
sub parseJson{
    my ($jfilename) = @_;
    if(-e "$jsoncPath/$jfilename"){
        return decode_json($json_data);
    }else{

    }
}
```

See the json below

```
[
   "searchTables.json",
   "NAM_database.json"
]
```

I also tried de-referencing as seen below with no success

```
print "<pre>First: ".@{$configFiles[0]}."</pre>";
```

give me what is sceen below.

```
First: 2
```

Comment: Tip: If you want to dump an array or hash, best to pass a reference. `Dumper(\@configFiles)`.

Comment: Thanks for that note, this provide a better picture of what is within the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`decode_json`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#decode_json) returns a reference to an array not the actual array.
Should be:

```
my $configFiles = parseJson($jfilename);
print "<pre>Array: " . Dumper($configFiles) . "\n";
print "First: " . $configFiles->[0] . "\n";
print "Second: " . $configFiles->[1] . "</pre>";
```

or

```
print "<pre>Array: " . Dumper(@configFiles) . "\n";
print "First: " . $configFiles[0][0] . "\n";
print "Second: " . $configFiles[0][1] . "</pre>";
```

Comment: This worked `$configFiles[0]->[0]` and also the following `@{$configFiles[0]}[0]`

Comment: `$configFiles[0]->[0]` can be shortened to `$configFiles[0][0]`

Answer (score 2):

The `@configFiles` is not the array you think/expect. The first element is an array reference, you need to dereference it to access the array:

```
print "ARRAY: @{$configFiles[0]}\n";
```

Comment: I tried this with no success

    `print "<pre>First: ".@{$configFiles[0]}."</pre>";`

give me what is sceen below.

    `First: 2`

Comment: @AndreDixon In scalar context, an array returns its size, not its elements. Using the concatenation operator `.` puts an array in scalar context. If you just use interpolation you'd be fine: `print "<pre>First: @{$configFiles[0]}</pre>"`

Comment: Or just change your concatenation dot into a comma - `print "<pre>First: ", @{$configFiles[0]}."</pre>";`